# How to prevent Numeric data when:HTML Input type = "text"?

Tags: php, html, input

I currently have a html/php registration page setup with first name & last name text fields, but i'd like to prevent inputs of numeric data (limiting input to alphabetic letters only) This is probably a duplicate question but i just couldn't seem to find anything while researching. How can i prevent user's numeric inputs?

```
<tr>
  <th> <label for = "firstname">Firstname </label> </th>
  <td> <input type = "text" name = "firstname" id = "firstname" value = "<?php echo isset($firstname)?$firstname:''; ?>" required /> </td>
</tr>

 <tr>
    <th> <label for = "lastname">Lastname </label> </th>
    <td> <input type = "text" name = "lastname" id = "lastname" value = "<?php echo isset($lastname)?$lastname:''; ?>"required /> </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Don't (do such filtering). About people's name this is a mandatory reading: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Unfortunately, one of my requirements for this project is to have validation on these particular fields..

Comment: Maybe, but again thinking that all firstname and lastname are only alphabetical letters is a huge mistake. So you while forbid sir O'Brian to use your website?

Comment: i was able to allow special characters but disabled numeric values 0-9

Comment: See the link in my previous comment and its point 15. People's names may have digits, so it is wrong to filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can by accomplish by using [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in javascript.

So on a [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) it will check if the current key pressed is one of the alphabetic letters.

In my example I used [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to cancel the keypress if a non alphabetic letter entered.

[Example](https://codepen.io/NdyU/pen/XPbeeg)

```
window.onload = function() {
  firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
  //Listen for keypress in the firstname input
  firstname.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    char_regex = RegExp('[A-Za-z]')
    //Prevent the key to be entered if it's not one of the alphabetic
    if(!char_regex.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
}
```

However, it's always a good idea to double check the input in the server code.

Comment: Hey there, how do i go about putting this into my php document? Or do i need to include any files? or just copy and paste that statement?

Would it be 
 `<script>
    window.onload = function() {
  firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
  //Listen for keypress in the firstname input
  firstname.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    char_regex = RegExp('[A-Za-z]')
    //Prevent the key to be entered if it's not one of the alphabetic
    if(!char_regex.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
} 
</script>`

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine. Or you can create a javascript file with that code, and include the file in your html page using the script tag.

Comment: With regards to this answer, i've found a less "wordy" solution in regards to java, tyvm, I found two files which contains javascript to prevent the keydown/keyup/entry of numeric values into text fields.

Comment: Also, on another note would you be able to guide me on how to create an input mask for a telephone field? 
`<tr>
  <th><label for = "telephone">Telephone number </label> </th>
  <td><input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo isset($telephone)?$telephone:''; ?>" required />
 </td>
  </tr>`

Comment: I recommend you to check this [source](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking) for information on creating input mask using an external library.

Comment: These seems useful, but i'm not sure how to go about applying it to my document

Comment: I researched abit with regards to <script> tags, and figured out how to import and utilise this particular mask, ty

Comment: No Problem! Hope it helps

Comment: it did, perfectly; enjoy